# I want to find out query in which group by is followed by order by

Tags: mysql

I try to create db for application chat . I am having trouble getting the latest information from customers in chat responses such as One customer is talking to me. Then the second client wanted to talk to me. I want my customer ID on top so I can verify who has not responded yet

My table is messages

```
+---------------------------+---------------+
| msg_id  |  outgoing_id  | |      msg      |
+---------------------------+---------------+
| 1   |  511   |            | test          |
| 2   |  543   |            | Hi            |
| 3   |  775   |            | Hello         |
| 4   |  511   |            | bye           |
| 5   |  543   |            | i want to buy |
+---------------------------+---------------+
```

I have user query

**select * from messages left join users on tbmsg.outgoin_id = users.unique_id  group by outgoing_id   order by msg_id desc**

This gives me result as

```
msg_id  |  outgoing_id  |    msg

    1   |  775   |    Hello
    2   |  543   |    Hi
    3   |  511   |    test
```

But I want result like this.

msg_id  |  outgoing_id  |    msg

```
   1   |  543   |    i want to buy
   2   |  511   |    bye
   3   |  775   |    Hello
```

Comment: Msg_id 1 belongs to outgoing_id 511. It makes no sense to associate it with a different outgoing _id. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Yes, like @Strawberry said,  I think you have made a mistake with your 'test' msg, it is associated to the 511 outgoing_id, but so is 'bye'. Maybe add a primary key constraint to your table to avoid this kind of issue

Comment: I try to create db for application chat . I am having trouble getting the latest information from customers in chat responses such as
One customer is talking to me.
Then the second client wanted to talk to me. I want my customer ID on top so I can verify who has not responded yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suspect you're after is the following, which, incidentally, renders your question amongst the most frequently asked under this tag...

```
select x.* 
  from my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT outgoing_id 
            , MAX(msg_id) msg_id 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY outgoing_id
     ) y 
    ON y.msg_id = x.msg_id 
   AND y.outgoing_id = x.outgoing_id 
 ORDER 
    BY msg_id DESC;
```

Comment: I try to create db for application chat . I am having trouble getting the latest information from customers in chat responses such as One customer is talking to me. Then the second client wanted to talk to me. I want my customer ID on top so I can verify who has not responded yet.

Comment: Great. This does that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
       @rowid := @rowid + 1 AS ROWID,t.*
  FROM messages t, 
       (SELECT @rowid := 0) dummy
       
       WHERE
        msg_id IN (select  max(msg_id)
from messages
group by outgoing_id) ORDER BY msg_id DESC
```

I agree with the comments that you shouldn't change the Primary key in the result but if you want a row number at the beginning you can use this query.
You can replace this with  **ROW_NUMBER()** if you are using Mysql Version **8.0+**

Result :

| ROWID | msg_id | outgoing_id | msg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 543 | i want to buy |
| 2 | 4 | 511 | bye |
| 3 | 3 | 775 | Hello |

Comment: User variables are effectively deprecated at this point, and will presumably be removed entirely from future releases of MySQL/MaraiDB.

Comment: @Strawberry I have mentioned ROW_NUMBER() if mysql version is 8+, so I cant see a point in down voting it.

Comment: I try to create db for application chat . I am having trouble getting the latest information from customers in chat responses such as
One customer is talking to me.
Then the second client wanted to talk to me. I want my customer ID on top so I can verify who has not responded yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
            FROM ( select outgoing_msg_id , MAX(msg_id) msg_id FROM messages GROUP BY outgoing_msg_id) a 
            LEFT JOIN (select unique_id , fname FROM users WHERE NOT unique_id = '0' AND status = '1') b 
            on a.outgoing_msg_id = b.unique_id
            ORDER BY a.msg_id DESC
```

That correct.